# When Azure AD and identity server message exchange by cookies are not available?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, azure-active-directory, session-cookies, identityserver4

I am having a setup with IS4 working as a federated gateway to Azure AD.
Everything was working fine until something happened and I do not receive cookies from Azure AD anymore.
The server is setup as follows:

```
 IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //Add this line

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
         {
             options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
             options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
             options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
             options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
             options.PublicOrigin = settings.PublicOrigin;
             options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
             {
                 CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
                 CookieSlidingExpiration = true
                 ,
             };
         })
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(persistKey: false)
            .AddCustomUserStore()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Sign-in with Azure AD", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie()
            .AddLocalApi(options => options.ExpectedScope = "api");

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>("aad", options =>
                    {
                        options.Scope.Add("openid");
                        options.Scope.Add("profile");
                        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                        options.ResponseType = "id_token";

                    });

        // preserve OIDC state in cache (solves problems with AAD and URL lenghts)
        services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache("aad");
```

The client as follows:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "implicit",
                ClientName = "Implicit Client",
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,

                RedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://notused" },

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                EnableLocalLogin=false,
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "api"},
            },
```

I got the samples from [Quickstarts](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/) and adapted them to my needs.
Everything was working fine until it didn't.

It fails here:

```
result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

As it does not  find any Cookies on the context. How can I troubleshoot this problem?
And when (what conditions) the Cookies are not present on the context usually? (Given that they are supposed to be)
I am not using AspNet Identity. I only want external login.

Comment: This may be related to SameSite cookie settings. Is anything logged in your browser console during the exchange?

Comment: I think so too, that it is related to same site cookie. But same site is None and I have nothing logged in my browser console. There are some cookies present but I cannot see the cookie idsrv.external (not even for working clients) and as a consequence other cookies are not emitted either.